# Handshake failure with "SSL error code -1/1/336032856" on OS X 10.7

Tags: svn, ssl, osx-lion

```
svn co "https://example.com/svn" 
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://example.com/svn': SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856 (https://example.com)
```

It works on Windows and Mac OX10.6, but it fails on Mac OSX10.7.

I've tried with the default /usr/bin/svn (version 1.6.16 (r1073529)),
and the one of fink /sw/bin/svn (version 1.6.17 (r1128011))
I installed all OSX10.7 updates.

What can be the problem?

ps: I use a private svn repository; "https://example.com/svn" is just an example for this post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is answered in the Subversion FAQ. See [*"When performing Subversion operations over SSL, I get the error SSL handshake failed..."](http://subversion.apache.org/faq#ssl-error-336032856):

> This can happen when the hostname reported by the server does not the match hostname given in the SSL certificate. Make sure your server configuration uses correct values for ServerName and NameVirtualHost.

A client-side fix is to update OpenSSL to version 1.0.0d.

Comment: A server-side solution when Apache is involved, is to make sure the ServerName matches the value in the cert.  On Ubuntu precice, this could be done with: echo "ServerName www.example.com" >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Comment: I still get the same error with openssl version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Comment: I follow this guide: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/updating-svn-mac-os-x/ for mountain lion and works great!

Comment: I had some trouble with this where none of the other fixes worked under svn 1.7, but svn 1.8(which no longer uses neon) fixed the issue.

Comment: @Edenshaw, I had to additionally upgrade svn to 1.8 to get around this.  So, I installed homebrew, then upgraded openssl, then upgraded svn.  I'm basically speechless.  Mix of victory and disdain for Apple's lack of support...

Answer (score 0):

If the other answer does not work

try

update your svn to version 1.7.8