# SVN issue / ssl handshake failed

Tags: svn, ssl, commit, handshake

I know other issues such as this one have been posted but none helped to fix my case.

I currently have to commit on an enterprise svn repo and got the following error :

```
svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://svn.myenterprise.com/subversion/path_to_project'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.myenterprise.com/subversion/path_to_project': SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856 (https://svn.myenterprise.com)
```

I recently updated my password in the enterprise environment, and the svn access is supposed to be based on this one. Notice that I can access to the repo through a web browser very easily using my new credentials.

I cleaned in the .subversion cache all the reference to previously cached credentials as well as in keychain.

I am currently working with :
Mac OX 10.9
svn --version 1.7.0
OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

Most other subjects suggested to update svn / openssl but it should be good on my side.

Any ideas on the subject ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: not even the answer to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078712/svn-osx10-7-ssl-handshake-failed-ssl-error-code-1-1-336032856) helped you?

Comment: as I remember, I does not helped. To be sure, I will retry tomorrow and keep this post updated accordinly, but following the suggest URL (http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/updating-svn-mac-os-x/) did not helped.
Thanks

Comment: Couple of questions.  What does `svn --version` report?  What does `openssl s_client -connect svn.myenterprise.com:443` output?  On the latter command the important thing is to very that the verify return code is 0 (meaning it passed certificate verification).  Note that newer versions of Subversion have improved error messages around SSL certificates so it may be helpful to upgrade since it'll potentially give you more information about what is wrong.

Comment: Hi Ben, 
svn is 1.7.0
I will check tomorrow at the office the return value for openssl
Thanks !

Comment: Hi Ben, at the very end of the openssl s_client -connect I got the following :

    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)