# Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew

Tags: macos, svn, openssl, homebrew

I'm using MacOS X 10.7.5 and I need a newer OpenSSL version due to [handshake failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363259/osx10-7-ssl-handshake-failed). There are several tutorials on the internet and I tried the following:

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
```

Nevertheless, it does not work:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011

brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e... 1139 links removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e... 1139 symlinks created
```

The SVN issue is not resolved either. Any ideas? I would rather not try the MacPorts way because it may interfere with Homebrew.

Comment: Be glad it didn't work. Version 0.9.8r didn't suffer from HeartBleed bug. If you successfully upgraded in March 2013, whatever SSL certificate you created is compromised and you have to rekey it now again. see heartbleed.com for affected versions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww  This is Stackoverflow and please let it be helpful. There will be some questions which will be in a shade of grey. I have stopped asking the question because of people who vote for closing a question without trying to understand the devs.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you're using Homebrew */usr/local/bin* should already be at the front of `$PATH` or at least come before */usr/bin*. If you now run `brew link --force openssl` in your terminal window, open a new one and run `which openssl` in it. It should now show `openssl` under */usr/local/bin*.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I reference this doc on how to add to $PATH: http://hathaway.cc/2008/06/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: In my case I put this on my ~/.profile PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin

Comment: I have installed `1.0.2h_1`, but I am exactly on the same  situation, but `openssl version -a` still gives me `OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Exactly same thing happened to me. It's fixec by @Marc Smith answer

Comment: This one doesn't work because
`brew link --force openssl
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

Comment: @TimoLehto Were you able to resolve this issue? Am facing same issue and cant seem to find a solution anywhere

Comment: @TuhinaSingh Sorry no luck, other than "following the instructions" and not linking the system library, but instead linking on demand with flags whenever I need it for compile or just calling the brew version directly i.e. `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1/bin/openssl`

Comment: @TimoLehto No idea if this is 'good practice' or even safe to do, but you could always create a link from /usr/local/bin to /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl. This can be done using the following command:
`ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl`.
To be clear: I can't promise you that this is a safe or correct way of proceeding.

Comment: more info on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/homebrew-refusing-to-link-openssl

Answer (score 16):

installed openssl on mac with brew but nothing found on `/usr/local/bin` where other brew installed bins are located. Found my fresh openssl here:

`/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl`

Run it like this:

`/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl version`

I don't want to update OS X openssl, while some OS stuff or other 3rd party apps may have dependency on older version.

I also don't mind longer path than just `openssl`

Writing this here for all the Googlers who are looking for location of openssl installed by brew.

Answer (score 15):

In a terminal, run:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
brew link --force openssl
```

You may have to unlink openssl first if you get a warning: `brew unlink openssl`

This ensures we're linking the correct openssl for this situation. (and doesn't mess with .profile)

Hat tip to @Olaf's answer and @Felipe's comment. Some people - such as myself - may have some pretty messed up PATH vars.

Comment: It just says `Refusing to link: openssl`

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue and found that the installation of the newer `openssl` did actually work, but my `PATH` was setup incorrectly for it -- my `$PATH` had the ports path placed before my brew path so it always found the older version of `openssl`.

The fix for me was to put the path to `brew` (/usr/local/bin) at the front of my `$PATH`.

To find out where you're loading `openssl` from, run `which openssl` and note the output. It will be the location of the version your system is using when you run `openssl`. Its going to be somewhere other than the `brew`path of "/usr/local/bin". Change your `$PATH`, close that terminal tab and open a new one, and run `which openssl`. You should see a different path now, probably under /usr/local/bin. Now run `openssl version` and you should see the new version you installed "OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013".

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question regarding updating openssl I followed these steps to successfully update the version found on my Mac to the newest openssl version 1.0.1e.

I followed the steps found here: http://foodpicky.com/?p=99

When you reach the steps for terminal commands **make** and **make install** be sure to use **sudo make** and **sudo make install** (I had to go through the step-by-step twice because I did it without sudo and it did not update).

Hope this helps

Comment: FYI as of today, 1.0.1e (specifically 1.0.1a-f) is known to have a serious security vulnerability. Future readers, make sure you upgrade to at least 1.0.1g http://heartbleed.com/

Comment: The old version is still showing for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974590/brew-link-force-openssl-did-not-update-openssl-version

Comment: ***Minus One***: *"... be sure to use sudo make..."* - You don't make with privileges. You just `make` and and then `sudo make install` if needed. You also cited a horrible reference. It replaces Apple's OpenSSL 0.9.8 in `/usr` with the updated 1.0.x. That's a really bad thing to do because there's no binary compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

I had problems installing some Wordpress plugins on my local server running php56 on OSX10.11. They failed connection on the external API over SSL.

Installing openSSL didn't solved my problem. But then I figured out that CURL also needed to be reinstalled.

This solved my problem using Homebrew.

```
brew rm curl && brew install curl --with-openssl

brew uninstall php56 && brew install php56 --with-homebrew-curl --with-openssl
```

Answer (score 2):

On mac OS X Yosemite, after installing it with brew it put it into

> /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl

But kept getting an error "Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure" when trying to link it

So I just linked it by supplying the full path like so

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

So now when I do

`$ openssl version -a`

It's showing version OpenSSL 1.0.2o.

So I guess it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

Afterwards try:

```
brew install homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

On OSX Big Sur, I had a very frustrating experience with the error, because all of the solutions lean on using `brew install`. But running `brew install` was always returning an error like:

```
Error: 
  homebrew-core is a shallow clone.
To `brew update`, first run:
  git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
This command may take a few minutes to run due to the large size of the repository.
This restriction has been made on GitHub's request because updating shallow
clones is an extremely expensive operation due to the tree layout and traffic of
Homebrew/homebrew-core and Homebrew/homebrew-cask. We don't do this for you
automatically to avoid repeatedly performing an expensive unshallow operation in
CI systems (which should instead be fixed to not use shallow clones). Sorry for
the inconvenience!
```

But I couldn't run that command because git was failing with:

```
% git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-https
  Reason: image not found
```

In the end, the solution was to **reinstall** git.

```
brew reinstall git
```

And then update symlinks, if necessary:

```
brew link --overwrite git
```

Answer (score 0):

For those, who are using macOS Monterey and are installing latest `openssl v3` with brew, it's located in completely different path:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/
```

A specific version is installed in the subfolder and the binary is reachable at (example for v.3.0.7):

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.7/bin/openssl
```

Using `brew link --force openssl` is still valid to create symlinks. Though it creates symlinks, the system openssl installed in /usr/bin/openssl has a preference because it's located earlier in the `$PATH` list.
So the solution will be to set the local symlink:

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.7/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

This preserves 2 version in different path but /usr/local/bin has the highest priority when searching in `$PATH`.
The drawback is that you'll need to update a symlink once a new version updated with brew because each version is located in a separate subfolder now.

Answer (score -11):

1. install port: `https://guide.macports.org/`
2. install or upgrade openssl package: `sudo port install openssl` or `sudo port upgrade openssl`
3. that's it, run `openssl version` to see the result.

Comment: The question was about Homebrew... macports is not homebrew... The OP states they prefer not to use mac ports.

Comment: @WadeWilliams mac in new version dose not let you update `openssl` using `Homebrew`, I mean you can install or update it using `Homebrew` but you can not prioritize it. So, instead of updating it using  `Homebrew` you can update it using `macports ` and prioritize it.