# Can't install OpenSSL 1.0.1e

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew

I've tried to install a new version of OpenSSL via Homebrew but it doesn't work. My actual OpenSSL version is 0.9.8 and I don't know what to do.

When I type on MacOS 10.8.4 `brew install openssl` the system brings to me the following error:

```
Error: openssl-1.0.1e already installed
```

So when I type `openssl version` I see this:

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
```

How can I turn the actual version to the new version installed via Homebrew? Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that OS X has an older version of openssl in /usr/bin, and Homebrew places it's version in /usr/local/bin

Try

> /usr/local/bin/openssl version

Edit: Before you try the above command, run:

> brew link --force openssl

Comment: I had to install Homebrew to test for my self. Try the command in my updated answer, that worked for me.

Comment: And as pointed out in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/openssl-version-macosx-homebrew/17231736#17231736) answer, you could/should edit your $PATH variable so that /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin.