# 'php composer.phar diagnose' errors

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I am getting following errors while trying to run php composer.phar diagnose.

```
php composer.phar diagnose
Checking composer.json: FAIL
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
require.google/apiclient : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.querypath/QueryPath : unbound version constraints (>=3.0.0) should be avoided
Checking platform settings: FAIL
The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.

Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com oauth access: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

My Question is how to remove the following failure:

```
Checking platform settings: FAIL
The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or     TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer Errors On Mac OpenSsl used by php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041034/composer-errors-on-mac-openssl-used-by-php)