# Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError | Bundle SSL issues on Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ssl

Im having issues all of a sudden when i run `bundle update`. It produces the following error:

```
Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError
```

I haven't added any new gems, ruby version is the same, etc.

Things i've done so far...

- RVM update
- Ruby 2.2.3 reinstall
- rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
- brew is working well

Not sure what else to do here. It just started today.

Comment: the gemfile doesn't say https does it?

Comment: `brew doctor` and `brew update` and `brew install openssl`. For more information, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/update-openssl-on-os-x-with-homebrew/15484406 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x.

Comment: @Jaison Brooks. Were you able to solve it? I had a same problem. Did the brew link openssl worked well?

Comment: @harshs08 To be honest the only fix was removing the https and replacing it with http. But, im baffled; why would it work for many months and all of a sudden change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your using a gemfile you can change rubygems source 'http://rubygems.org'

also you can try running `gem update --system`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by:

1. Uninstall `openssl-osx-ca` if you have it already

   `brew uninstall openssl-osx-ca`
2. Uninstall and install `openssl`

   `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl`

   `brew install openssl`
3. Check if brew is all well

   `brew doctor`
4. Reinstalled the ruby version which had the

   `` rvm reinstall <ruby-version> --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl` ``

I think there is some issue with the brew installed openssl, like the previous version not having some dependencies required by rvm to compile ruby cleanly.

Comment: I recently upgraded to OS X High Sierra, and bundler would no longer work. All I needed was step 2, and now it's working fine. Thanks!