# Receiving error when executing the step 3 of installing Socket.IO C++ Client

Tags: c++, node.js, boost, cmake, socket.io

I want to install Socket.IO C++ Client from "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp", but I have some difficulties following the steps from "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/INSTALL.md". I have successfully installed boost version 1_73_0 (step 1) and run step 2. I have some difficulties with step 3. When I run `cmake -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0 -DBOOST_VER:STRING=1.73.0 ./`
I receive this error:

```
    -- not define build type, set to release
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1491 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.73.0;1.73"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1492 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "ON"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1493 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1494 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = "OFF"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1495 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1496 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1528 ] BOOST_ROOT = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1529 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1530 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1531 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1532 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1533 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1621 ] location of version.hpp: /Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1661 ] Boost_VERSION = "107300"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1662 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.73.0"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1663 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107300"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1664 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1665 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "73"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1666 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1667 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1691 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:801 ] _boost_COMPILER = <unset> (guessed)
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1728 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1805 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1810 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1870 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1871 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-mt-1_73;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:656 ] Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:658 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-mt-d-1_73;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt-d;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:656 ] Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:658 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_date_time-mt-1_73;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:656 ] Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:658 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_date_time-mt-d-1_73;boost_date_time-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:656 ] Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:658 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2056 ] Searching for RANDOM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_random-mt-1_73;boost_random-mt;boost_random-mt;boost_random-mt;boost_random
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:656 ] Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:658 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2111 ] Searching for RANDOM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_random-mt-d-1_73;boost_random-mt-d;boost_random-mt-d;boost_random-mt;boost_random
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:656 ] Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib"
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.18.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:658 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0/stage/lib;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH"
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Home/Documents/GitHub/socket.io-client-cpp
```

My environment is mac and I installed boost at `/Users/Home/Documents/boost_1_73_0` and Socket.IO C++ Client is at `/Users/Home/Documents/GitHub/socket.io-client-cpp`

I also installed the static version of boost by `./b2 link=static,shared`

I would appreciate it if you let me know what is wrong. I also tried `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` as well, but it was not helpful. I am very new to programming, so I would be grateful if you make your answer as simple as possible.

Comment: I don't see a Boost error. The error I do see says, "Could NOT find OpenSSL...." Do you have OpenSSL libraries installed?

Comment: Thanks @metal. Yes, and when I run `brew install openssl`, I receive this: `Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 5 formulae.

Warning: openssl@1.1 1.1.1g is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.1.1g, run `brew reinstall openssl@1.1``

so it is already installed

Comment: I suggest you set `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` to the right spot, as the error message hints. (Disclaimer: I'm not a Mac user.) The comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17231736/201787) suggest that this is a feature, not a bug, since it prevents you from accidentally linking to old versions of OpenSSL.